# Pandas lambda function won't recognize NaN

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, nan

I'm trying to evaluate a new column in a DF by values from two others, but if a value is missing I try to pass another expression.

```
df_merge["3"] = df_merge.apply(lambda row: row["1"] + row["2"] 
    if pd.isnull(row["1"]) or pd.isnull(row["2"])
    else (row["1"] + row["2"])/2, 
    axis=1)

                         loc              1               2               3
    0                   135200           0.391           0.224          0.3075
    1                   135210           0.400           0.220          0.3100
    95                  136150             NaN           0.505             NaN
    96                  136160             NaN           0.527             NaN
```

This is what I got. So if 1 or 2 is null I want to use the first expression, else the last one.
However, the first expression never gets passed. If I try to test for example:

```
pd.isnull(df_merge.iloc[96,3])
```

It evaluates to True, so why isn't the first expression passed in that instance??

I also tried:

```
df_merge["3"].fillna(value=df_merge["1"] + df_merge["2"],inplace=True)
```

Which did exactly nothing.

Sincerely,
Fredrik

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: can you provide an example for a small df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest here is use `mean` per rows, because mean by default in pandas omit `NaN`s (if not both NaNs like row `2`):

```
df_merge = pd.DataFrame({'1':[np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2],
                   '2':[5, np.nan, np.nan, 4]})

df_merge["3"] = df_merge[["1",'2']].mean(axis=1)
print (df_merge)
     1    2    3
0  NaN  5.0  5.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  NaN  1.0
3  2.0  4.0  3.0
```

Comment: That worked great! Did not know that mean motted NaN's. But I still don't understand why my first suggestion did Not work? For purely educational purposes ofcourse. NaN in python is not very intuitive..

Comment: @FredrikNiva - I tested and also working weird. Also there was problem only first `if pd.isnull(row["1"])` was tested, and another problem was `row["1"] + row["2"]` - it return NaNs in one of value or both was nans. So finally I got `df_merge["3"] = df_merge.apply(lambda row: row[["1",'2']].sum()
    if row[["1",'2']].isna().any()
    else (row["1"] + row["2"])/2, 
    axis=1)`, but it is really complicated.

Comment: Hm, alright. That is a highly unsatisfactory result (no fault of you of course). Thankfully your first, more aesthetically pleasing, solution worked like a charm. Thank's for the swift reply!